Problem with bluetooth connection between two esp32s
I am trying to make a heart rate and SpO2 sensor that I can wear on my wrist using the microcontroller of Firebeetle Espressif ESP32, the sensor of MFMYUANHAN MAX30105, and the battery of a Small Li-Po battery (3.7V). The sensor will be Bluetooth-connected continuously with another watch that will also be using the same model of ESP32. However, currently, the Bluetooth from the esp32s will not connect with each other and I can not receive any data from the sensoring watch on the receiving watch. I tried to debug by checking my phone's Bluetooth status, but it doesn't show up. Could the issue be with my board?
Sensoring Watch Code:
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MAX3010x.h>
#include "filters.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_SPP_ENABLED)
#error Serial Bluetooth not available or not enabled. It is only available for the ESP32 chip.
#endif

// Bluetooth setup
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
const char *pin = "1234"; // Bluetooth pairing code
String slaveName = "ESP32-BT-Slave"; // Bluetooth slave device name
String myName = "ESP32-BT-Master"; // Bluetooth master device name

// Sensor setup
MAX30105 sensor;
const auto kSamplingRate = sensor.SAMPLING_RATE_400SPS;
const float kSamplingFrequency = 400.0;

// Finger Detection Threshold and Cooldown
const unsigned long kFingerThreshold = 10000;
const unsigned int kFingerCooldownMs = 500;

// Edge Detection Threshold (decrease for MAX30100)
const float kEdgeThreshold = -2000.0;

// Filters
const float kLowPassCutoff = 5.0;
const float kHighPassCutoff = 0.5;

// Averaging
const bool kEnableAveraging = true;
const int kAveragingSamples = 5;
const int kSampleThreshold = 5;

// Filter Instances
LowPassFilter low_pass_filter_red(kLowPassCutoff, kSamplingFrequency);
LowPassFilter low_pass_filter_ir(kLowPassCutoff, kSamplingFrequency);
HighPassFilter high_pass_filter(kHighPassCutoff, kSamplingFrequency);
Differentiator differentiator(kSamplingFrequency);
MovingAverageFilter<kAveragingSamples> averager_bpm;
MovingAverageFilter<kAveragingSamples> averager_r;
MovingAverageFilter<kAveragingSamples> averager_spo2;

// Statistic for pulse oximetry
MinMaxAvgStatistic stat_red;
MinMaxAvgStatistic stat_ir;

// R value to SpO2 calibration factors
float kSpO2_A = 1.5958422;
float kSpO2_B = -34.6596622;
float kSpO2_C = 112.6898759;

// Timestamp of the last heartbeat
long last_heartbeat = 0;

// Timestamp for finger detection
long finger_timestamp = 0;
bool finger_detected = false;

// Last diff to detect zero crossing
float last_diff = NAN;
bool crossed = false;
long crossed_time = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.println("Hello World");
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize Bluetooth
  SerialBT.begin(myName, true);
  Serial.printf("The device \"%s\" started in master mode, make sure slave BT device is on!\n", myName.c_str());
  SerialBT.setPin(pin);
  Serial.println("Using PIN");

  bool connected = SerialBT.connect(slaveName);
  Serial.printf("Connecting to slave BT device named \"%s\"\n", slaveName.c_str());
  if (connected) {
    Serial.println("Connected Successfully!");
  } else {
    while (!SerialBT.connected(10000)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to connect. Make sure remote device is available and in range, then restart app.");
    }
  }

  // Initialize sensor
  if (sensor.begin() && sensor.setSamplingRate(kSamplingRate)) {
    Serial.println("Sensor initialized");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Sensor not found");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  auto sample = sensor.readSample(1000);
  float current_value_red = sample.red;
  float current_value_ir = sample.ir;

  // Detect Finger using raw sensor value
  if (sample.red > kFingerThreshold) {
    if (millis() - finger_timestamp > kFingerCooldownMs) {
      finger_detected = true;
    }
  } else {
    // Reset values if the finger is removed
    differentiator.reset();
    averager_bpm.reset();
    averager_r.reset();
    averager_spo2.reset();
    low_pass_filter_red.reset();
    low_pass_filter_ir.reset();
    high_pass_filter.reset();
    stat_red.reset();
    stat_ir.reset();

    finger_detected = false;
    finger_timestamp = millis();
  }

  if (finger_detected) {
    current_value_red = low_pass_filter_red.process(current_value_red);
    current_value_ir = low_pass_filter_ir.process(current_value_ir);

    // Statistics for pulse oximetry
    stat_red.process(current_value_red);
    stat_ir.process(current_value_ir);

    // Heart beat detection using value for red LED
    float current_value = high_pass_filter.process(current_value_red);
    float current_diff = differentiator.process(current_value);

    // Valid values?
    if (!isnan(current_diff) && !isnan(last_diff)) {
      // Detect Heartbeat - Zero-Crossing
      if (last_diff > 0 && current_diff < 0) {
        crossed = true;
        crossed_time = millis();
      }

      if (current_diff > 0) {
        crossed = false;
      }

      // Detect Heartbeat - Falling Edge Threshold
      if (crossed && current_diff < kEdgeThreshold) {
        if (last_heartbeat != 0 && crossed_time - last_heartbeat > 300) {
          // Show Results
          int bpm = 60000 / (crossed_time - last_heartbeat);
          float rred = (stat_red.maximum() - stat_red.minimum()) / stat_red.average();
          float rir = (stat_ir.maximum() - stat_ir.minimum()) / stat_ir.average();
          float r = rred / rir;
          float spo2 = kSpO2_A * r * r + kSpO2_B * r + kSpO2_C;

          if (bpm > 50 && bpm < 250) {
            // Average?
            if (kEnableAveraging) {
              int average_bpm = averager_bpm.process(bpm);
              int average_r = averager_r.process(r);
              int average_spo2 = averager_spo2.process(spo2);

              // Show if enough samples have been collected
              if (averager_bpm.count() >= kSampleThreshold) {
                SerialBT.printf("HR:%d SpO2:%.1f\n", average_bpm, average_spo2);
                Serial.print("Time (ms): ");
                Serial.println(millis());
                Serial.print("Heart Rate (avg, bpm): ");
                Serial.println(average_bpm);
                Serial.print("R-Value (avg): ");
                Serial.println(average_r);
                Serial.print("SpO2 (avg, %): ");
                Serial.println(average_spo2);
              }
            } else {
              SerialBT.printf("HR:%d SpO2:%.1f\n", bpm, spo2);
              Serial.print("Time (ms): ");
              Serial.println(millis());
              Serial.print("Heart Rate (current, bpm): ");
              Serial.println(bpm);
              Serial.print("R-Value (current): ");
              Serial.println(r);
              Serial.print("SpO2 (current, %): ");
              Serial.println(spo2);
            }
          }

          // Reset statistic
          stat_red.reset();
          stat_ir.reset();
        }

        crossed = false;
        last_heartbeat = crossed_time;
      }
    }

    last_diff = current_diff;
  }
}

Receiving Watch Code:
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MAX3010x.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include "filters.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run make menuconfig to and enable it
#endif
#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_SPP_ENABLED)
#error Serial Bluetooth not available or not enabled. It is only available for the ESP32 chip.
#endif

// Bluetooth setup
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
const char *pin = "1234"; // Bluetooth pairing code
String device_name = "ESP32-BT-Slave"; // Bluetooth device name

// Display setup
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
#define OLED_RESET     -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

bool display_reset = true;

void initDrawScreen(void); // Function declaration
void displayMeasuredValues(bool no_finger, int32_t beatAvg, int32_t spo2); // Function declaration

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin(device_name); // Start Bluetooth serial
  Serial.printf("The device with name \"%s\" is started.\nNow you can pair it with Bluetooth!\n", device_name.c_str());
  SerialBT.setPin(pin);
  Serial.println("Using PIN");

  // SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC = generate display voltage from 3.3V internally
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { 
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    while (1);
  }

  display.clearDisplay();
  initDrawScreen();
}

void loop() {
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    String receivedData = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println("Received Data: " + receivedData);

    // Extract HR and SpO2 values from the received data
    int hr = 0;
    float spo2 = 0;
    if (sscanf(receivedData.c_str(), "HR:%d SpO2:%f", &hr, &spo2) == 2) {
      displayMeasuredValues(false, hr, spo2);
    } else {
      displayMeasuredValues(true, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}

// Function to initialize the display screen
void initDrawScreen(void) {
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);             // Normal 1:1 pixel scale
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);        // Draw white text
  display.setCursor(0,0);             // Start at top-left corner
  display.println(F("    Test The Code"));
  display.println(F(""));
  display.setCursor(5, display.getCursorY());
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.println(F("BPM  %SpO2"));
  display.display();
}

// Function to display measured values on the screen
void displayMeasuredValues(bool no_finger, int32_t beatAvg, int32_t spo2) {
  display.setCursor(5,35);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE, BLACK);
  if(no_finger) {
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.println(F("NO Finger            "));
    display_reset = true;
    display.display();
  } else if(beatAvg < 30 && display_reset) {
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.println(F("Pls.  Wait             "));
    display_reset = false;
    display.display();
  } else if(beatAvg >= 30) {
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.println(F("             "));
    display.setCursor(5,35);
    display.setTextSize(3);
    display.print(beatAvg);
    display.print(F(" "));
    if(spo2 >= 20 && spo2 <= 100) {
      display.print(spo2);
    } else {
      display.print(F("--"));
    }
    display.println(F("    "));
    display.display();
  }
}

